# Convert CSV to HTML Table (Searchable & filterable)?

Tags: html, csv, report, html-table, alternate

Is there is any alternative program/Project for converting CSV to Dynamic HTML Table along with search & filtration,which would be use for reporting on Client side.

Currently, I'm using [CSV To HTML](https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Python tool called [csvtotable](https://github.com/vividvilla/csvtotable) which uses [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) for the client-side. From their documentation:

> Convert `data.csv` file to `data.html` file
>
> `csvtotable data.csv data.html`